# Postgres stored procedure not performing updates

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

Here is the relevant C# code:

```
NpgsqlConnection? con = null;
NpgsqlCommand? cmd = null;

try
{
    RawFileInfo rfi = CreateRawFileInfo(blobData);

    if (rfi == null || rfi.Ids.Count == 0) 
        return;

    con = new NpgsqlConnection(postgresConnection);
    con.Open();

    cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("CALL shipment_status.updatefilelocation(@ids_to_update, @files_to_update, @start_with, @end_with)".ToLower(), con);

    cmd.Parameters.Add("ids_to_update", NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Uuid);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("files_to_update", NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("start_with", NpgsqlDbType.Integer);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("end_with", NpgsqlDbType.Integer);
    cmd.Parameters["ids_to_update"].Value = rfi.Ids.ToArray();
    cmd.Parameters["files_to_update"].Value = rfi.RawDataStorageLinks.ToArray();
    cmd.Parameters["start_with"].Value = 0;
    cmd.Parameters["end_with"].Value = rfi.Ids.Count - 1;

    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch
{
    throw;
}
finally
{
    if (cmd != null)
    {
        cmd.Dispose();
        cmd = null; 
    }   

    if (con != null)
    {   
        con.Close();
        con = null;
    }
}   //end finally
```

And here is the procedure itself:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE shipment_status.updatefilelocation(
    ids_to_update uuid[],
    files_to_update text[],
    start_with integer,
    end_with integer)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
    DECLARE counter INT;
    DECLARE currentID UUID;
    DECLARE currentFILE TEXT;
BEGIN
    counter := start_with;  
    WHILE counter <= end_with LOOP
        currentID := ids_to_update[counter];
        currentFile := files_to_update[counter];
        UPDATE shipment_status."RawShipmentStatusMissingSCACCode"
        SET "RawDataStorageLink" = currentFile
        WHERE "Id" = currentID;
        COMMIT;
        UPDATE shipment_status."RawShipmentStatusMissingShipmentStatusCodeMap"
        SET "RawDataStorageLink" = currentFile
        WHERE "Id" = currentID;
        COMMIT;
        counter := counter + 1;
    END LOOP;       
END;
$BODY$;
```

The procedure appears to execute when called, but it is returning -1 and no update occurs.

I have tried different things with the placement of the `COMMIT`, or with the assignment and where clauses, for example, initially I did not have the variables `currentID` and `currentFile`, but was doing the assignment directly, e.g.

```
SET "RawDataStorageLink" = files_to_update[counter] WHERE "Id" = ids_to_update[counter]
```

but the behavior was the same.

Thanks....

Comment: I would look at the Postgres log and see what is actually hitting the database.

Comment: Adrian Klaver I will do that, thanks

Comment: From your call to the stored procedure can be seen that never enters the while loop since `cmd.Parameters["start_with"].Value = 0;  cmd.Parameters["end_with"].Value = rfi.Ids.Count - 1;` 0<=-1

Comment: Pepe N O
Not so: if I have, say, 1 item in my Ids collection, I will start with 0, and end with 0: the loop specifies less than OR equal...
But you point me in the right direction: I find this: "By default PostgreSQL uses a one-based numbering convention for arrays, that is, an array of n elements starts with array[1] and ends with array[n]." source: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html

I was assuming zero-based indexing. I will correct for this and see what happens.

Thank you!

Comment: Solved: it was me assuming zero-based, rather than one-based, indexing. When I pass the start and end using one-based: it works. 

Thanks much, Pepe N O, your comment put me on the right track!

Comment: In your posted code the values are hardcoded, anyway don't try to blindly find out what's wrong with your code. Debug writing to console your variables using `raise notice 'some variable %', some_variable;` and monitor the PostgreSQL log with `sudo tail -f your_postgres_path/log/<current_logfile>` from `SELECT pg_current_logfile();`

Comment: The values are... not hard-coded? Assuming a zero-based array, specifying zero for the first element is entirely reasonable; and assuming the count minus one, for the last element, is standard. 
As it turns out, there was nothing "wrong" with the code, in this case; it was a matter of understanding how Postgres handles array indices by default...
Thanks though

Comment: @Chris you are right, I didn't see `rfi.Ids.Count - 1`

Comment: No worries mate :)